# Java VM doesn't work with `android.util.*`: Mutable classes cannot be initialized with value other than zero

Tags: java, android

I am using Android Studio 3.1.2 with API level 26 and min API 21. I checked and saw that package `android.util` has type `MutableDouble` with implementation like this:

```
package android.util;

/**
 */
public final class MutableInt {
  public int value;

  public MutableInt(int value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

But when I initialize new instance of `MutableDouble` with specific input value, it always receives zero value like this:

```
MutableDouble d = new MutableDouble(999d);
System.out.println("Received value: " + d.value);
=> "Received value: 0.0"
```

I have to set the value directly to make it work

```
MutableDouble d = new MutableDouble(999d);
d.value = 777d;
System.out.println("Received value: " + d.value);
=> "Received value: 777.0"
```

I have copied above implementation of `MutableDouble` to my own project and it worked as expected.

Checking other similar classes like `MutableInt`, `MutableFloat`, etc. and they have the same issue.

Did anyone face this issue like me? Any wrong configuration in Android Studio causes this?

Comment: Huh, I am unable to reproduce, that is weird.  Only difference I can see is I am in Android Studio 3.0.1

Comment: @Popmedic Thanks for trying reproduce. I have checked with my other PC with the same project and it still happens. I will try with new project to see any differences.

Comment: I wonder if it is because they have deprecated the class.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/MutableDouble  I would STRONGLY advise not using Mutable classes like this because of the risk with concurrency.

Comment: Maybe use an `AtomicLong` instead: `AtomicLong d = new AtomicLong(Double.doubleToLongBits(99.9));
        System.out.println("Double is set to " + Double.longBitsToDouble(d.longValue()));`

Comment: _I wonder if it is because they have deprecated the class_: Yes, I wonder too. But this is not the good way to deprecate something. Thanks for your advice about concurrency, I use these Mutable classes because this is a short way to **pass args as references** to functions in Java.

Comment: Not sure there is a good way to deprecate something, would you rather it just disappear?   I suggest using the `AtomicLong` because you can still pass it as reference, but it is thread safe.

Comment: _Not sure there is a good way to deprecate something_ I mean make its behavior weird and different from implementation is not the good way to deprecate it.

Comment: I could not agree more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe these functions are [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/MutableDouble), and as such will not work correctly when using Android Studio >= 3.1.0 (Android P SDKs).  I don't know why they deprecated the MutableInt, MutableDouble,... classes but would assume it is because passing literals by reference can be really dangerous with asynchronous applications, and they are **really** easy classes to implement!  I would suggest using an AtomicLong like so:

```
AtomicLong d = new AtomicLong(Double.doubleToLongBits(99.9));
System.out.println("Double is set to " + Double.longBitsToDouble(d.longValue()));
```

which would be **much** safer to pass by reference.

There is also a [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AtomicDouble.html) AtomicDouble class you could use if you are ok bringing in the Guava package.

Another idea is to create a simple AtomicDouble class of your own using the AtomicLong, like so:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import static java.lang.Double.*;

class AtomicDouble extends Number {

    private AtomicLong bits;

    public AtomicDouble() {
        this(0.0);
    }

    public AtomicDouble(double initialValue) {
        bits = new AtomicInteger(doubleToLongBits(initialValue));
    }

    public final boolean compareAndSet(double expect, double update) {
        return bits.compareAndSet(doubleToLongBits(expect),
                                  doubleToLongBits(update));
    }

    public final void set(double newValue) {
        bits.set(doubleToLongBits(newValue));
    }

    public final double get() {
        return longBitsToDouble(bits.get());
    }

    public double doubleValue() {
        return get();
    }

    public final float getAndSet(double newValue) {
        return longBitsToDouble(bits.getAndSet(doubleToLongBits(newValue)));
    }

    public final boolean weakCompareAndSet(double expect, double update) {
        return bits.weakCompareAndSet(doubleToLongBits(expect),
                                      doubleToLongBits(update));
    }

    public float floatValue() { return (float) doubleValue(); }
    public int intValue()       { return (int) get(); }
    public long longValue()     { return (long) get(); }

}
```

Comment: Your answer is more details and have more approaches. So I choose it to my question rather than mine.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out that the issue happens when run tests on native Java VM. Run tests on Android VM, they work as expected.

Re-read [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests), I guess all packages under namespace `android.*` must be used with Android VM to work properly.

Wondering why there are no warning/error message when run tests on Java VM to inform this case.